# How to show multiple images with a for loop

Tags: plotting, graphics, image

I wrote a simple application(I put the code in the end) to detect the parallel line pairs in the following picture:
[image]

It returned three pairs of parallel line:

```
{{{{584., 222.175}, {39.6747, 0.}}, {{0., 377.639}, {390.613, 472.}}}, 
{{{0., 403.894}, {306.413, 0.}}, {{0., 336.953}, {238.095, 0.}}}, 
{{{584., 186.489}, {127.104, 0.}}, {{0., 377.639}, {390.613, 472.}}}}
```

And then I want to show every result individually. Here's the way I output the result, where img is the test picture and parLines is the detected parallel line pairs.

```
For[i = 1, i <= Length[parLines], i++,
Show[img, Graphics[{Thick, Orange, Line /@ parLines[[i]]}]]]
```

I expected it to output several images and a pair of parallel lines on each. The number of images depend on the number of pairs of parallel line. However, it didn't draw anything. But if I printed them one by one, it worked fine.

```
Show[img, Graphics[{Thick, Orange, Line /@ parLines[[1]]}]]
```

[image]

```
Show[img, Graphics[{Thick, Orange, Line /@ parLines[[2]]}]]
```

[image]

```
Show[img, Graphics[{Thick, Orange, Line /@ parLines[[3]]}]]
```

[image]

I can't understand where the problem is. Thanks for any help.

---

Here's the code:

```
img = Import["http://www.zechini.it/webtv/upload/book.jpg"];
edge = DeleteBorderComponents[EdgeDetect[img]];
lines = ImageLines[edge, 0.1];

NumofLines = Length[lines];
flag = False;
parLines = {};
For[i = 1, i <= NumofLines, i++,
  For[j = i + 1, j <= NumofLines, j++,
    line1 = lines[[i]];
    line2 = lines[[j]];
    vec1 = line1[[1]] - line1[[2]];
    vec2 = line2[[1]] - line2[[2]];
    para = 1 - ArcCos[Abs[(vec1.vec2)/Norm[vec1]/Norm[vec2]]]/(Pi/2);
    If[para > 0.9, flag = True; AppendTo[parLines, {line1, line2}];];
    ];
  ];

If[flag == True,
 For[i = 1, i <= Length[parLines], i++,
  Show[img, Graphics[{Thick, Orange, Line /@ parLines[[i]]}]]], 
 Print["Cannot detect parallel line"]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or perhaps:

```
Show[img, Graphics[{Thick, Orange, Line[#]}]] & /@ parLines
  // GraphicsRow
```

[image: books]

Answer (score 6):

This is probably what you want (whenever you're using `For` loops to generate a static result like a combined `Graphics`, you have to be suspicious that you're doing it wrong):

```
Show[img, 
 Table[Graphics[{Thick, Orange, Line /@ parLines[[i]]}], {i, 1, 3}]]
```

[image: book]

In words: replace the `For` loop by a `Table` inside the `Show` if you want all lines to be shown in the *same* `Graphics`.

In case I misunderstood: if you want to *really* use a `For` loop despite all this, you can force output of the `Show` result at every step by replacing `Show` by `Print@Show`. This is needed because `Graphics` is only shown when it's the last statement in a compound expression (and not followed by a `;` which stands for `CompoundExpression`). But in the `For` loop, the `Show` is not the last command that gets executed.

Comment: Actually I would like to use for loop to output every result individually, no in the same picture. Therefore I think Print@Show will suit my purpose

Answer (score 3):

Though this isn't an extension to the other answers you've received it might give you some insight into the Mathematica/Functional style of problem solving.

```
img = Import["http://www.zechini.it/webtv/upload/book.jpg"];
lines = ImageLines[DeleteBorderComponents[EdgeDetect[img]], 0.1];
```

By removing many of the redundant intermediate variables and concentrating on manipulating the data as a sequence of transformations the main body of code can be reduced to one line, plus one function definition.

Define a function  that returns true or false if a pair of vectors are parallel:

```
parallel[{vec1_, vec2_}] := (1-ArcCos[Abs[(vec1.vec2)/Norm[vec1]/Norm[vec2]]]/(Pi/2)) > 0.9
```

Then by creating a set of all the pairs of parallel lines we can then apply that to the result of building vectors from the pairs of lines:

```
parLines = With[{l=Subsets[lines, {2}]}, Pick[l, parallel/@Apply[Subtract, l, {2}] & /@ l)]];
```

Then display the results as per cormullion's answer:

```
Show[img, Graphics[{Thick, Orange, Line[#]}]] & /@ parLines // GraphicsRow
```

Comment: (+1) Is `VectorAngle` any use here?

Comment: I think you could use `Apply[Subtract, l, {2}]` in place of `((Subtract @@ # & /@ #) & /@ l)`. Perhaps it is even clearer to use Select instead of Pick: `Select[l, parallel[Subtract @@@ #] &]`

Comment: Impressive! That is very conise. I'm a beginner to Mathematica, and since I'm more familiar with C++ programming, my code looks C++-style. However, as a beginner, it is difficult for me to understand the parLines line you write. I can't imagine the output of every operation performed. I have to take that line apart and output every segments to understand how it works. Sometimes I even don't know how to decompose it! I would like to know what the core spirit it is to write the code so concise, and how? Well, I admit that my code up there is ugly :)

Comment: Well...I don't know if worth a new thread, if so I'll post it as a new question later.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use Manipulate to choose which lines to display:

```
Manipulate[Show[img, Graphics[{Thick, Orange, Line /@ parLines[[i]]}]], {i, 1, 3, 1}]
```

By moving the slider you can see each of the pairs of parallel lines in succession.

[image]

Comment: Or `ListAnimate` or `FlipView` ...